# getline function not compiling with mingw-w64 gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, getline, c-standard-library

I have a program2.c c code.
gcc program2.c gives the following error -
[image: gcc error]

I tried with various options like

1. gcc -std=gnu90 program2.c
2. gcc -std=c90 program2.c
3. gcc -std=c99 program2.c
4. gcc -std=c11 program2.c
5. gcc -std=gnu11 program2.c
6. g++ program2.c

None of the above compiled the file. Error was always similar.
Is there any way to compile this ?
Looks like getline is not part of c standard. But some compiler do support it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are right, getline is not part of the C standard. It's a POSIX standard function

Comment: I'd be surprised if the Windows C library has it.

Comment: In that case there is no way I could use getline function on a C program for windows. That's really weird. It's like loosing a lot of functionality. Whereas on linux box it works perfectly. There must be some compiler on which getline works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `getline` was never part of the C standard library, but is a Unix/POSIX extension. To get access to it, you need to compile with gcc in POSIX ("gnu") mode under Unix, in which case the compiler drops the function inside stdio.h. And dropping non-standard functions inside standard headers is non-compliant behavior.

To get this working under Windows, you'd need to use Cygwin to emulate Unix under Windows. The gcc/mingw port won't do, since that one uses Microsoft's C standard lib.

The good news is that you probably don't want to use `getline` anyway (even in POSIX), since that function has a horrible API and is a major source for memory leaks in buggy C programs. It's one of those strange, ancient Unix functions that simply should be avoided. Instead consider using `fgets` with a caller-allocated buffer: faster, safer, portable standard C.

Comment: I tried on cygwin. It didn't worked there also. `fgets` is probably a good idea. I was trying to read in a file. So used getline for taking in variable length input. Also I am taking a variable line of any length as input in my program. Can `fgets` be used to same effect. `getline` automatically allocates memory.

Comment: @pensee It depends on the expected file format. Usually it's fine to just statically allocate some temporary buffer of 256 or so bytes then use `fgets`.

Comment: What if I am taking a string as input from user. Now I don't know if the user will enter a string with 1000 chars or 10000 chars. So allocating buffer beforehand won't work. Also could you give some reasons why `getline` has a poor API. Any reference or online links?

Comment: @pensee The fact that it allocates memory that people always forget to clean up is the major one. And also potential issues with the size parameter, when it is written to and not written to by the function. There's also misc problems with ssize_t, EOF and "in-band error indicators", see [CERT-C ERR02-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/ERR02-C.+Avoid+in-band+error+indicators), which could in theory be a security problem. (But then the whole of stdio.h with or without extensions is just one big security problem to begin with...)

Comment: @pensee And you really shouldn't accept use input that long. Limit it to what makes sense for the application. Otherwise the user could in theory feed massive input to make the heap overflow and crash the program or in worst case the whole system.

Comment: Okay. So the way I was coding using getline is it allowed user to enter strings of any length. That had an appeal and looked like a perfect program. But there is an issue as you said it could lead to heap overflow. So is it always best to restrict user to strings of certain length ? Or in cases where we want to allow it to be very large length. Probably use realloc and check it yourself rather than relying on something like getline. What about reading a file where a line of file could be very long. So `stdio.h` should be avoided as you suggested. What's the alternative library?

Comment: @pensee The alternative lib would be whatever GUI your program is using. People don't really write that much in the way of console I/O in the year 2021. For various system programming, command-line parameters are often used instead of direct user input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for enlightening discussion.

Comment: When u use the word POSIX/Unix extension. Does that mean getline was introduced only for Unix and never for windows? Is POSIX = UNIX ? Is there any good online reference for C standards? So that one could clearly see which functions are in C and which are not so that the code is portable. I wrote the getline code in ubuntu and landed in trouble when I tried executing it on windows. Although it's a different topic of discussion why are these extensions introduced in Unix?

Comment: @pensee Basically first there was Unix, then came Linux, and then some Unix/Linux people decided "oh wouldn't it be great if there was a technical standard saying that our OS is the correct one and everyone else is wrong", then published the POSIX standard saying that *nix is now the standard. *nix `man` generally states if a function fulfils standard C and/or POSIX. If they are standard C they are very portable, if they are POSIX, they are at least portable in the *nix world.

Comment: I check online. I found that C was released in 1972 and Unix in 1971. And then "Unix was written in c and assembly". I don't understand that if C was not released till 1972. How they built Unix in 1971. Also what I understand from your last comment, is that POSIX was mainly built by `UNIX` guys and not the `C` guys

Comment: C library doesn't seem to include things like `sockets`. But `POSIX` does include it. Looks like th basic functionality of C standard is too less. So is it like I can't code networking stuff in `C`?

Comment: @pensee This is getting wildly off-topic. And you can easily answer this yourself by reading about Unix on wikipedia. "The operating system was originally written in assembly language, but in 1973, Version 4 Unix was rewritten in C."  As for POSIX it didn't come around until late 90s. And regarding C, it's a general purpose language so it knows nothing about stuff such as memories, screens or data communication.